# How to make Header table with foreach in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, export-to-excel

I made Excel export on Laravel, but I have trouble making it using Foreach, I usually use array and I want the name of field get from variable in foreach

```
$headings = array(
    'No', 
    'Name', 
    'IC',
    'Employer', 
    'Loan Amount Disbursed', 
    'Date Disbursed'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` like

```
foreach($headings as $key => $value) {
    // $key is the index i-e       [0]
    // $value is the content item  [No] 
}
```